# Using sed to remove text between two characters

Tags: bash, sed

I am new at shell scripting and using sed and need help to remove text between two specified characters (not including the characters). I need to remove between > and =

For example

```
> hello the email is = 123@gmail
```

becomes

```
123@gmail
```

Currently I have, but it is not even outputting a result.

```
sed -e 's/\('>'\).*\(=\)/\1\2/' file.txt > fileEdited.txt
```

Comment: "not including the characters" and your example contradict. In the example you removed `>` and `=` and even the following space. Please [edit] and make it consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed` to group the element you want to pass through:

```
sed -e 's/^>.*= \(.*\)/\1/' file.txt
```

Here, the match for the substitution `^>.*= \(.*\)` starts with a caret to ensure you match the angle bracket at the beginning of the line. Then `.*` matches everything between the `>` and `=`. There is a literal space after the `=` but could be replaced with `\s*` to match any whitespace. The group `\(.*\)` grabs everything left to become `\1` on the replace segment.

Here is the whole thing on one line to test:

```
echo "> hello the email is = 123@gmail" | sed -e 's/^>.*=\s*\(.*\)/\1/'
```